# Why does my window or application minimize when its child process exists?

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, gnome-shell-extension

I am experiencing a strange issue with `Ubuntu 18.04` that I don't know could have been caused by a wrong configuration or a conflict from recent application installs. What happened was whenever the child process of a GUI application exists, the parent GUI minimizes. Example cases would be:

Example 1:

> Open `Naulius`, find a tar file and open it by double clicking. Select
> `/tmp` then click `Extract`. Immediately, the `File Roller` app that
> just extracted the files minimizes.

Example 2:

> Open `Nautilus`, right click on a folder, click `Open in New Window`.
> Once the new window opens, close it. Immediately, the parent window
> also minimizes

Example 3:

> Open `Terminal`, type `file-roller`. Once the `File Roller` opens,
> close it. The `Terminal` window also minimizes. This also happens with
> `gnome-calculator`. But this issue does NOT happen with `firefox` or
> `gedit`.

Comment: Not normal behaviour, and certainly can't reproduce. You will need to think about the configuration changes you effectuated. Temporarily make a new account and check if the issue also occurs there. Likely not, so then it will be an issue with your user configuration. You may then want to reset that to some extent.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?